# The following code is giving me an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, string, list, split, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to decipher a message from a text file by getting the mode of each column and is giving me an attribute error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

I know that list has no `split`, only strings have `split`.

```
file1=open("input.txt","r")
for row_ele in file1.readlines().split("\n"):
    c=0
    for ele_in_row in row_ele:
           #c=row_ele.count(ele_in_row):
            if c<row_ele.count(ele_in_row):
                c=row_ele.count(ele_in_row)
                mode_ele=ele_in_row
    print(mode_ele)
file1.close()
```

Comment: Well: readlines returns a list of strings AND splitting those lines with '\n' will yield the original line and an empty string ... you can probably just remove the `split('\n')` because that is what readlines() already does for you.

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you the problem: you are trying to call `split()` on a list, but list has no function called `split()`. I think you want to take a string and split it into a list of lines separated by `'\n'` which you could do if you had a string because `str` has a function named `split()`. `readlines()` already does this, so you can just remove the call to `split()` entirely:

```
for row_ele in file1.readlines():
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have used the `readline()` it became `file1 = {'line1', 'line2', ...}`. You can only use

```
for row_ele in file1.readlines():
```

or

```
for row_ele in file1.split('\n'):
```

Comment: file doesn't have a `split()` method. You would need to read the entire file into a string first, but `readlines()` should be preferred anyway.